# How to store each line of a file in a matrix?

Tags: ruby

I have a text file with this structure:

```
regular: 12/09/2010, 15/09/2012, 16/09/2012
rewards: 17/09/2010, 18/09/2012, 19/09/2012
rewards: 20/09/2010, 21/09/2012, 22/09/2012
```

And I want to store it in matrix like this:

```
my_matrix = [['regular', '12/09/2010', '15/09/2012', '16/09/2012'],
             ['rewards', '17/09/2010', '18/09/2012', '19/09/2012'],
             ['regular', '20/09/2010', '21/09/2012', '22/09/2012']
            ]
```

I've tried this:

```
File.open(text_file).each_line do |line|

    @costumer_request = line.delete!(':').split
    @costumer_request = line.delete!(',').split
```

But it returns this:
`@costumer_request ['regular', '20/09/2010', '21/09/2012', '22/09/2012']`

How Can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File.open(text_file){|io| io.each_line.map{|line| line.split(/[:,\s]+/)}}
```

Comment: The file should by closed by calling `File#close` explicitly or using the block form `File.open do |f| ... end` which will close the file implicitly.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell After the edit, that is ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16300619/revisions

Comment: The first version of the code worked fine for me, but, the edited  version produced: IOError: closed stream

Answer (score 2):

```
File.open('foo', 'r') do |f|
  f.lines.map do |line|
    line.chomp.split /[:,] /
  end
end

#=> [
# ["regular", "12/09/2010", "15/09/2012", "16/09/2012"],
# ["rewards", "17/09/2010", "18/09/2012", "19/09/2012"],
# ["rewards", "20/09/2010", "21/09/2012", "22/09/2012"]
#]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your format is exactly the one you are showing you can also do:

```
File.open(file).each_line.map do |l|
    l.split.map { |e| e.chomp(/,:/) }
end
```

Comment: `split(' ')` is equivalent to just `split` ;-)

Comment: Fun fact: when you actually want to split *only* at spaces you even need a regex! Consider `"a\tb c\nd".split #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]` which looks fine. Now let's split at the space: `"a\tb c\nd".split(' ') #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]` wtf? We actually need a regex: `"a\tb c\nd".split(/ /) #=> ["a\tb", "c\nd"]` i find this very surprising and  for me, `split` seems somehow broken by trying to be too smart.

Comment: It is needed to close file if block isn't used. (a = File.open(file).each_line{}); a.closed? # false